# Sweetalert confirm button does not work on laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert

I have a problem, when I want to confirm that I agree to submit data, but nothing happens. There is no response if the data is successfully submitted.

**Form Script :**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="{{ route('Upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" class="formsubmit">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="judul">Judul:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control @error('judul') is-invalid @enderror" id="judul" placeholder="Masukan Judul" name="judul" >
        @error('judul')
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input @error('file') is-invalid @enderror" name="file">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Pilih Berkas Maks. 2 MB</label>
        @error('file')
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>
    </br></br></br>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Autentikasi" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript :**

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                swal({
                    icon: "warning",
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Do you want to submit and pay 10 Rupiah",
                    buttons: ["No, cancel pls!", "Yes, send it!"],
                })
                .then((value) => {
                    console.log('form submitted');
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Please Help me, so that the data after being confirmed can be submitted and a success alert appears

[Sweetalert confirm button does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4qxl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should write "fire" after "swal".
like this

```html
 <script>
 $(document ).ready(function() {
            $('#form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                swal.fire({
                    icon: "warning",
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Do you want to submit and pay 10 Rupiah",
                    buttons: ["No, cancel pls!", "Yes, send it!"],
                })
                .then((value) => {
                    console.log('form submitted');
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, once added the sweetalert doesn't appear.